# Mozilla Thunderbird new message arrive notification only from selected senders

Tags: email, thunderbird, notifications

Is there any way (setting, option, plug-in, etc.) to configure Mozilla Thunderbird "When new message arrive" notification shows only from selected senders?

My users receive more than 200 emails per day. Including newletters, less important emails and emails from very important customers. Last ones expect the reaction immediately or less than 5 minutes, but my user has other tasks to do too.

I'm interested out-of-the-box solutions too. For example third-party notifier softwares.

Is there any way to set up Mozilla Thunderbird to show notifications from selected users only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extensions such as [Mailbox Alert](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/?src=search), which, "allows you to specify, for each seperate [sic] mail folder, a message, sound and/or a system command that will be executed when new mail is found there."

- Create a folder for a sender or a group of senders.
- In Thunderbird *Tools | Message Filters*, create a filter to direct mail from the specified recipients to that folder.
- Set an Alert when messages arrive there.

*Caveat*, I've not tested that extensions myself.